# How show TOAST every click on checkbox in list view?

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I need to show TOAST every click on checkbox into my list view.

This is my code:

```
public  class MyListFragment extends Fragment implements
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{



    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    static PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;
    ListView listView;
    String user="";
    private Spinner spinner;
    String selState;
    EditText cristo;
    private String zao;
    private CheckBox ck;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;
    private static Context context = null;
    private static FragmentActivity mInstance;

    Integer[] imageId = {
            R.mipmap.androtuto,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ok,
            /*R.drawable.image6,
            R.drawable.image7*/

    };



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the custom_spinner_items for this fragment
        //super.onDestroy();

        SharedPreferences settings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);





        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getContext());
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);



        context = getActivity();
        mInstance = getActivity();
    //  txtName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    //  txtEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.numero_telefonico);
        btnLogout = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        //spinner  = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
//      selState = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        //cristo=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ck=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);




        return rootView;
    }







    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



        lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();


    }


    private void displayPlanetList() {

        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add(new Planet("Margherita", "6", "€","(pomodoro e mozzarella)"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Diavola", "7","€","(pomodoro,mozzarella e salsiccia piccante)"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Bufalina", "5","€","(pomodoro e mozzarella di bufala)"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Marinara", "5", "€","(pomodoro)"));
        planetList.add(new Planet("Viennese", "4", "€", "(pomodoro,mozzarella e wrustel)"));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, getContext(),imageId) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
                    p.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),
                    "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                            + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }
        };

        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
    }



    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        String pizzeOrdinate="";

        for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.isSelected()){
                pizzeOrdinate+="\n" + p.getName() + " " +p.getTipo()  + " " +p.getDistance() + "€" + "q.tà :" + p.getQuantità();

            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + pizzeOrdinate + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)


    public String showResultTotale2(View v) {

        //selState=cristo.getText().toString();


        int totalAmount=0;
        String pizzeOrdinate="";

        for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.isSelected()){
                pizzeOrdinate+="\n" + p.getName() + " " +p.getTipo()  + " " +p.getDistance() + "€" + "q.tà :" + p.getQuantità();

            }
        }
        return pizzeOrdinate;
    }
```

The method showResultTotale2() works if I click on button, but I want the same method that works on every click on checkbox.

Who can help me?Thanks in advance!

ADAPTER CLASS:

```
public abstract class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnClickListener

{
    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context ;
    ArrayList<Birra> objects;
    public boolean Checked;
    private Integer[] imageId;
    String ciao;
    static PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    String selState ;

   /* public PlanetAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item);
    }
*/

    /*public PlanetAdapter(FragmentManager fm,List<Planet> planetList, Context context,Integer[] imageId) {


        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item,planetList);


        this.fm=fm;
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = context;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
*/
    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context,Integer[] imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item,planetList);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = context;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }


    public class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetName;
        public TextView distView;
        public TextView valuta;
        public CheckBox chkBox;
        public EditText edit;
        public TextView caratteristica;
        public boolean checked;
        public TextView id;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public Spinner spinner;
        public EditText edit2;
        public Button iterator;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return planetList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Planet getItem(int position) {
        return planetList.get(position);
    }







    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        PlanetHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
            holder = new PlanetHolder();
            holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            holder.valuta = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.valuta);
            holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
            holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            holder.spinner = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.simpleSpinner);
            holder.edit2 = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
          //  holder.iterator = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.iterator);
           // Button iterator=(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.iterator);
           // iterator.setOnClickListener(this.PlanetHolder);
            holder.caratteristica=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.caratteristica);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
            holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            // holder.id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);


            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        final Planet p = planetList.get(position);
        System.out.println("stampato P" + p);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
        holder.valuta.setText("" + p.getValuta());
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
        holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
        holder.caratteristica.setText(p.getCaratteristica());
       holder.edit.setEnabled(false);

        SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isChecked = states.getBoolean("holder.chkBox" + holder.planetName.getText().toString(), false);
        System.out.println(isChecked);
        if (isChecked) {
//            holder.chkBox.setChecked(true);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(true);
            holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.edit2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            SharedPreferences statess = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String string = statess.getString("finalHolder.edit" + holder.planetName.getText().toString(), holder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
            holder.edit.setText(string);


        } else {
            holder.chkBox.setChecked(false);
            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
            holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit2.setVisibility(View.GONE);


         }
        final PlanetHolder finalHolder2 = holder;


        holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(PlanetAdapter.this);

        // final BirraHolder finalHolder = birraHolder;
        final PlanetHolder finalHolder = holder;
        Planet z=getItem(position);
        System.out.println(z);
        final PlanetHolder finalHolder1 = holder;
        final PlanetHolder finalHolder3 = holder;
        holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                    finalHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                            getContext(),
                            R.array.country_arrays,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    //finalHolder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    finalHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            finalHolder.spinner.setSelection(position);
                          //  selState = finalHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                         //   p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                            p.setTipo(finalHolder.spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

                            finalHolder.edit2.setText(selState);
                          //  System.out.println(selState);
                            System.out.println("p.getTipo()"+p.getTipo());

                           /* Toast.makeText(
                                    getContext(),
                                    "Clicked on Planet: " + selState + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/



                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                        }


                    });



                    SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox" + finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), true);
                    editor.commit();
                    finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                            SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                            editor.putString("finalHolder.edit" + finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                            editor.commit();


                        }
                    });

                  /*  SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox" + finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), true);
                    editor.commit();*/
                    //Utility.putPizzaItem(p);
                    //Utility.getPizzaItem(p);


                } else {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                    finalHolder.edit.setText("");
                    finalHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                }

            }
        });

        /*holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (finalHolder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(true);
                    SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("holder.chkBox", true);
                    //pizzaSelected.put(p.getId(), p);
                    System.out.println(p.getId());
                } else {

                    finalHolder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    finalHolder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                    finalHolder.edit.setText(null);
                    pizzaSelected.remove(p.getId());

                }

            }
        });
*/


       /* finalHolder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                p.setQuantità(finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                SharedPreferences states = getContext().getSharedPreferences("states", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = states.edit();
                editor.putString("finalHolder.edit" + finalHolder.planetName.getText().toString(), finalHolder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                editor.commit();


            }
        });
*/

       // holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
       // holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
       // holder.valuta.setText("" + p.getValuta());
       // holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
       // holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
       // holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
        //  holder.id.setId(p.getId());


        return row;
    }







    ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        for (Planet p : planetList) {
            if (p.isSelected())
                box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }



    }
```

Comment: Your issue isn't really much clear. Also, share only the relevant code

Comment: showResultTotale2  method works if i click on button. But i want that this method works if i click on every checkbox not on button

Comment: How many checkboxes do you have? Are there checkboxes in the list items (because I already see a check change listener in your adapter)?

Comment: i have  5 checkboxes in listview......

Comment: So, the toast in `onCheckedChanged` in the adapter doesn't work?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: no error.....only that toast not appear

Comment: Put the line `Log.d("POS", pos);` right after `int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);`

Comment: you refer at what method onCheckedChange? i have two method onCheckedChange in my class

Comment: The one you set in your adapter. Also, now that you say it, share the code for your adapter.

Comment: yes, the first onCheckedChange works but only for one checkbox not for all selected

Comment: Share the code for your adapter class

Comment: i shared adapter class

Comment: I posted an answer based on what I did understand

Comment: So, you're `Lo_Zio` too!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to provide a check change listener to your adapter. Firstly, we modify the adapter constructor:

```
public abstract class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> implements View.OnClickListener {

    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckListener;

    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context, Integer[] imageId, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item,planetList);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = context;
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.mCheckListener = checkListener;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckListener);
        ...

    }

}
```

Now, in your `fragment`, set your adapter as:

```
   plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, getContext(),imageId, new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // Do your stuff here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok...try to diagnose the problem. You get any errors, compiler warnings, did you try to use breakpoints, etc. share the info with me

Comment: i not give any error...but toast not appear when i click on all checkbox

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/ see this tutorial...i want same but not onClick button....but when i click on checkboxes

Comment: @Markus Try to use breakpoints, you'll know what you're dong wrong